# Static fields in stateless session beans

Tags: java, static, ejb

If I have a static fields in a stateless bean :

```
@Stateless
@Local(SomeClass.class)
public class AccountBean implements SomeClass{

   private static final int STATIC_FIELD = 0;

   public AccountBean () {}
}
```

Will the `STATIC_FIELD` value be shared in all `AccountBean` instances, like in basic classes?

**EDIT** Mark the field as `final` as suggested bellow.

Comment: You may use them as constants (`public/private static final type`). But you shouldn't use them for sharing the state. It may work in 1 JVM environment, but once you deploy the application into cluster, the state won't be shared across multiple JVMs (different classloader => different static variable).

Comment: @Jiri thank you to point this consideration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it will be shared, but only inside a single JVM of course. And its capitalization indicates that it's a constant, and should thus be `final`.

If it's not a constant, then it smells, doesn't respect tha Java naming conventions, and violates the EJB spec.

Comment: Thank you that's all I wanted to know :) Yes I forgot to add `final` word, I did not copy/paste, I know this convention

Comment: +1 for pointing out that static fields in stateless entity beans should be final.